# QUARQ DFour installation on Shimano bike

Tags: shimano, crankset, bottom-bracket, power

I'd like to replace my Ultegra 6800 crankset with QUARQ DFour powermeter. But I don't know how to choose between BB30 and GXP versions. I have Shimano Pressfit SM-BB92-41B bottom bracket. Do I need to replace my bottom bracket or use some adapters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Shimano SM-BB92-41B is a BB92 standard bottom bracket.

Quarq's page lists GXP, Press Fit GXP, BB30, Press Fit 30, BBright, BB386EVO, BB30A, PF30A as compatible bottom brackets.

I believe the Press Fit GXP from SRAM is a BB92 standard bottom bracket. See https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-standards-1#article-section-4.

So the GXP version is the  one you want. It would be nice if Quarq provided a better compatibility guide.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I decided to buy the GXP version. If it's not compatible with my BB, I will replace the bottom bracket and update my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Finaly I ordered GXP version and SRAM GXP PressFit bottom bracket. Now all works fine. My old Shimano BB not compatible with GXP cranks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about how this worked out - although I'm disappointed I was wrong about the  compatibility. Can I ask how was the crank not compatible with the Shimano BB bearings?

Comment: While bearings from Shimano BB have the same internal diameter, bearings from Sram BB have the different. Sram bearing on non-drivetrain side has slightly smaller internal diameter. Sram bearing on drivetrain side has the same internal diameter as Shimano bearings.

Comment: Very useful info - thanks. I think Park Tool's info meant that GXP PF fits into a frame designed for BB92.